# In the current version of the GitHub for Windows UI, is there a way to see unsynced commits?

Tags: windows, git, github

Using version 3.3.3.0: There is a button in the upper right to sync but I do not see a way to list commits that have not yet been pushed to the remote server.

While watching a training video for an older version, the repo view clearly showed the list of unsynced commits on the left above the history: [image: previous version].

Answer (score 1):

If the commit is unsynced, it will show you a circle outline in the timeline. Sadly it cannot be seen in the history log that it is unsynced.

[image]

Click on the circle to see the commit. Any commits with a circle outline are unsynced commits.

Hope this helped!